# Selenium WebDriver Working with Three Frames. Not able to locate the element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm very new to Selenium Webdriver. I'm trying to automate an webpage and i'm facing two issues.  I couldn't able to click the Search button in the frame. Below is my code.

```
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120,1000);

     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("frameview"));

     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("epilowerframe"));

     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("productSearchIframe"));

     driver.switchTo().frame("frameview")
     .switchTo().frame("epilowerframe")
     .switchTo().frame("productSearchIframe");

    driver.findElement(By.id("styleSearchForm:goBtn")).click();
```

the StylesearchForm:goBtn is inside the productsearchIframe .

I'm always getting the error:

> Timed out after 120 seconds waiting for frame to be available: epilowerframe
>   Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_33'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
>       at Nike_Demo.main(Nike_Demo.java:59)

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can try to click by xpath?

Comment: Just to be sure - are you certain that the frames are nested? If they are nested, you're ok and djangofan's answer probably applies to you. If not, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt is already switching the driver to the frame.
You don't need to do:

```
 driver.switchTo().frame("frameview")
 driver.switchTo().frame("epilowerframe")
 driver.switchTo().frame("productSearchIframe");
```

Just use the code:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120,1000);

 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("frameview"));
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("epilowerframe"));
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("productSearchIframe"));

 driver.findElement(By.id("styleSearchForm:goBtn")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not oftend the problem, but sometimes, depending on the app, you could be switching frames too quickly.  You should put a 1-2 second pause after each time you call .switchTo() to get to a new frame.  That will give the browser driver time to load the new DOM before you do another switchTo().   Also, it sorta appears that you are switching to each frame twice; not sure if you noticed that.